# Creating a month by month view from table showing only a date of status change

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structured like:

```
id    changedate     status
1     1997-11-04   Installed
1     2010-01-10  Terminated
2     2015-10-05   Installed
```

The `changedate` above is the `MAX(ChangeDate) by Month`.

The goal is the create either a `table` or a `view` that shows month by month the status of each id, up to this month.

Example output:

```
id    changedate     status
1     1997-11-01   Installed
1     1997-12-01   Installed
1     1998-01-01   Installed
...
1     2010-01-10  Terminated
...
1     2017-04-01  Terminated
2     2015-10-01   Installed 
...
```

I am new to MySQL, and my brain wants to use a `LEAD()` function, however since that function is not supported in MySQL, I'm left stumped. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a table of months?

Comment: Yes, I do. Are you thinking `cross join`?